# ACF - Display a photo for selecting a checkbox in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce, acfpro

To sell my products, I need to display file types on the wc single product page.
for example :
html , css , js , svg

--- I wrote a code for this and it works fine.  But I feel it is not standard.

```
function acf_product_icon_type(){
    $prodoct_icon = get_field_object('product_type_icon');
    $icons = $prodoct_icon['value'];
    if( $icons ): ?>
<ul class="product-platform-selector">
    <?php foreach( $icons as $icon ): ?>
    <li><?php 
switch ($prodoct_icon['choices'][ $icon ]) {
    case "Illustrator":
        echo '<img src="/plat-ai.svg">';break;
    case "Photoshop":
        echo '<img src="/plat-ps.svg">';break;
    case "Xd":
        echo '<img src="/plat-xd.svg">';break;
    case "Lightroom":
        echo '<img src="/plat-lroom.svg">';break; 
}
    ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; 
}
add_shortcode('cicon', 'acf_product_icon_type');
```

Do you have a suggestion for a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function acf_product_icon_type(){
    $prodoct_icon = get_field_object('product_type_icon');
    $icons = $prodoct_icon['value'];
    if ($icons):
        $icons_img = array(
            'Illustrator' => 'ai',
            'Photoshop' => 'ps',
            'Xd' => 'xd',
            'Lightroom' => 'lroom'
                )
        ?>
        <ul class="product-platform-selector">
            <?php
            foreach ($icons as $icon):
                $icon_img_type = $prodoct_icon['choices'][$icon];
                ?>
                <li> <?php echo "<img src='/plat-" . $icons_img[$icon_img_type] . ".svg'>"; ?> </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
    endif;
}

add_shortcode('cicon', 'acf_product_icon_type');
```

Comment: You can't echo shortcode output.